# Spider-like movement without animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would I make a (let's say) spider move via placing the their legs correctly on the environment in **Unity**?

Do I use Raycasts? (Something like)

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Raycast(transform.position, transform.TranformDirection(Vector3.Down), 2, out hit))
{
   tranform.position = hit.transform.position;
}
```

Or is there another, more efficient way?

Comment: Please add more details, describe the result you want to see more clearly, and explain what this code suppose to do, and where is your problem.

Comment: Also I'm generally against this kind of work. It's usually too much for production, unless you make an AAA game for console, or maybe you want to do some experiment to learn something, it's not practical to put time and effort on some details like this. The end-user usually cares only about the total experiment, and details like this will only comes after that. IMHO

Comment: @MehdiSabouri I want the spider to place it's legs on a rocky terrain. Animation would make it look weird. But if each of it's legs placed their feet correctly on the ground, floor, etc. it is beneath, it would look natural.

Comment: Yoi might be interested in [Inverse Kinematics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html). This article [Procedural Animations](http://www.weaverdev.org/tutorials/procedural-animation/) shows some awesome examples and tutorials

Comment: @derHugo Thanks!